# maven build failing for annox:annotate tag

Tags: java, maven, annotations, swagger

I have a XSD schema project which I am trying to build but when I run the `clean install` command on the project I get below exception

Java version --> 1.8

```
 [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ gccm-common-
    bindings ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/shank030/Desktop/Workspace/gccm-common-bindings/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate (generate) @ gccm-common-bindings ---
[INFO] Up-to-date check for source resources [[file:/Users/shank030/Desktop/Workspace/gccm-common-bindings/src/main/interfaceDefinations/gccm-operations.xsd, file:/Users/shank030/Desktop/Workspace/gccm-common-bindings/src/main/resources/bindings.xml, file:/Users/shank030/Desktop/Workspace/gccm-common-bindings/pom.xml]] and taret resources [[]].
[INFO] Sources are not up-to-date, XJC will be executed.
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/Users/shank030/Desktop/Workspace/gccm-common-bindings/src/main/interfaceDefinations/common/CommonTypes.xsd{1937,22}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/Users/shank030/Desktop/Workspace/gccm-common-bindings/src/main/interfaceDefinations/common/CommonTypes.xsd; lineNumber: 1937; columnNumber: 22; compiler was unable to honor this annotate customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ErrorReporter.error(ErrorReporter.java:84)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.check(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:149)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.check(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:127)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.attributeDecl(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.AttributeDeclImpl.visit(AttributeDeclImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.attributeUse(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.AttributeUseImpl.visit(AttributeUseImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.attContainer(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:197)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.attGroupDecl(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:170)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.AttGroupDeclImpl.visit(AttGroupDeclImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.run(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.run(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:101)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder._build(BGMBuilder.java:181)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.build(BGMBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.annotateXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:425)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:174)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:50)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:40)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:488)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

My POM File configuration

```
<properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <jaxb.maven.version>1.6</jaxb.maven.version>
      <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
   </properties>
   <build>
      <finalName>gccm-common-bindings</finalName>
      <resources>
         <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
               <exclude>com/**/*.xsd</exclude>
               <exclude>com/**/.DS_Store</exclude>
               <exclude>com/**/*.drl</exclude>
            </excludes>
         </resource>
      </resources>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>generate</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>generate</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <extension>true</extension>
                     <args>
                        <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                     </args>
                     <schemaDirectory>src/main/interfaceDefinations/</schemaDirectory>
                     <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.xsd</include>
                     </schemaIncludes>
                     <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/</bindingDirectory>
                     <bindingIncludes>
                        <include>*.xml</include>
                     </bindingIncludes>
                     <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                           <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                           <version>1.0.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                           <artifactId>jaxb2-annotate-plugin-test-annox-annotations</artifactId>
                           <version>1.0.0</version>
                        </plugin>
                     </plugins>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
                  <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
                  <version>1.5.1-M2</version>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
         <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.1-M2</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting this issue.

Comment: suppose your `pom.xml` is incorrect. There is a `<dependencies>` inside your `<build>` which is stated in the stack-trace. Also double check your other `xml` files.

Comment: Not following you, what is the issue here @RajithPemabandu

Comment: there is `<dependencies>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
                  <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
                  <version>1.5.1-M2</version>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>` inside your `pom.xml` `<build>` tag.

Comment: I removed and tried still the same issue @RajithPemabandu

Comment: Can someone help here!